# Connection to remote docker host via TLS gives X.509 Certificate is incomplete

Tags: docker, kotlin

I want to connect to remote docker host via TLS and I have provided cert.pem, key.pem and ca.pem which I have validated to be present in the given path and identical to original keys.

My problem is that i get this error:

Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: X.509 Certificate is incomplete: SubjectAlternativeName extension MUST be marked critical when subject field is empty

I have checked with openSSL that my key has actually isCritical == true and when I connect to the host in terminal everything works fine.

When I debugged then in X509CertInfo where the exception is thrown the inputStream is used twice to create X500Name and for the first variable it works fine, but for the subject which is used to validate criticality gets empty subject because of empty stream:

issuer = new X500Name(in); -> gets content
subject = new X500Name(in); -> is empty

What can be the problem for me?

The code where I configure the docker client is this:

```
open fun produceDockerClient(
    platformId: String,
  ): DockerClient {
    val platform = ...
    val dockerConfiguration = platform.dockerConfiguration
    val dockerHostUrl = if (dockerConfiguration.isRemoteDockerHostEnabled) {
      dockerConfiguration.remoteDockerHostUrl ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("No remote docker host url defined")
    } else {
      LOCAL_DOCKER_HOST
    }
    val dockerCertsFolder =
      if (dockerConfiguration.isRemoteDockerHostEnabled &&
        dockerConfiguration.remoteDockerHostTLSCertificate != null &&
        dockerConfiguration.remoteDockerHostTLSKey != null &&
        dockerConfiguration.remoteDockerHostTLSCertificateAuthority != null
      ) {
        createTLSTempFiles(dockerConfiguration, platformId)
      } else {
        null
      }
    return createDockerClientImpl(dockerConfiguration.isRemoteDockerHostEnabled, dockerHostUrl, dockerCertsFolder)
  }

  private fun createDockerClientImpl(
    isRemoteEnabled: Boolean,
    dockerHostUrl: String?,
    certPath: String?,
  ): DockerClient {
    if (isRemoteEnabled && !CertificateUtils.verifyCertificatesExist(certPath)) {
      throw IllegalArgumentException("TLS certificate files do not exist in temporary folder")
    }

    val config: DefaultDockerClientConfig = createDefaultConfigBuilder()
      .withDockerHost(dockerHostUrl)
      .withDockerTlsVerify(isRemoteEnabled)
      .withDockerCertPath(if (isRemoteEnabled) certPath else null)
      .build()

    val httpClient: DockerHttpClient = Builder()
      .dockerHost(config.dockerHost)
      .sslConfig(config.sslConfig)
      .maxConnections(DOCKER_CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE)
      .connectionTimeout(ofSeconds(DOCKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS))
      .responseTimeout(ofSeconds(DOCKER_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS))
      .build()

    return getInstance(config, httpClient)
  }

  @Throws(IOException::class)
  open fun writePemFile(keyContent: String, keyType: String, filePath: String) {
    val newKeyContent = keyContent.replace(" ", "\n").trim()

    val pemContent = buildString {
      append("-----BEGIN $keyType-----")
      append("\n")
      append(newKeyContent)
      append("\n")
      append("-----END $keyType-----")
      append("\n")
    }
    FileWriter(filePath).use { fileWriter -> fileWriter.write(pemContent) }
  }

  private fun createTLSTempFiles(dockerConfiguration: DockerConfiguration, platformId: String): String {
    val folderPath = "/tls/$platformId"
    val folder = File(folderPath)
    folder.mkdirs()

    writePemFile(dockerConfiguration.remoteDockerHostTLSCertificate!!, "CERTIFICATE", "$folderPath/cert.pem")
    writePemFile(dockerConfiguration.remoteDockerHostTLSCertificateAuthority!!, "CERTIFICATE", "$folderPath/ca.pem")
    writePemFile(dockerConfiguration.remoteDockerHostTLSKey!!, "PRIVATE KEY", "$folderPath/key.pem")

    return folderPath
  }
```